# mounting the ntfs partition

Tags: linux, filesystems

could any one help to mounting the ntfs partitions on rhel 5.3. please send me the link of appropreate application.

Answer (score 2):

From the command-line:

```
# mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/<partition> /mnt/<folder>
```

From inside /etc/fstab

```
/dev/<partition> /mnt/<folder> ntfs-3g defaults 0 0
```

[More on ntfs-3g](http://www.ntfs-3g.org/)

Answer (score 0):

You should not need any special applications. It should already have the necessary modules installed. If it isn't, you may want to look up `ntfs-3g` in the repositories. You should be able to mount it just like any other filesystem.

```
# mount /dev/<partition> /mnt
```

Or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

I would say use cifs:

```
mount -t cifs //machinetomount/folderperhaps /mnt/machine -o credentials=/root/.smbcredentials.myadmin,iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777

root@mymachine:~# cat /root/.smbcredentials.myadmin 
username=myadmin
password=blabla
```

Comment: cifs is for mounting remotely filesystems over SMB. And plaintext passwords are bad style.

Comment: well you secure the file of course.

Answer (score 0):

I've recently used the NTFS Linux kernel driver from http://www.linux-ntfs.org to mount SAN-based NTFS partitions on my Red Hat 5.2 server. It works very well, though it is read-only. If you need read-write access to the NTFS partitions then *I think* you can use the ntfsmount utility from the same site, though I've not tried that myself.

Answer (score 0):

have you install require rpm for the

## rpm - qa | grep fuse

fuse-ntfs-3g-1.1120-1.el5.rf
fuse-2.7.0-2.el5.rf
dkms-fuse-2.7.0-1.nodist.rf

if is not then pls install the following

## yum install fuse fuse-ntfs-3g dkms dkms-fuse

## yum --enablerepo=rpmforge install fuse fuse-ntfs-3g dkms dkms-fuse

## yum install fuse-kmdl fuse

Suppose your ntfs filesystem is /dev/sda1 and you are going to mount it on /mymnt/win, do the following.

First, create a mount point.

mkdir /mymnt/win

Next, edit /etc/fstab as follows. To mount read-only:

/dev/sda1       /mymnt/win   ntfs-3g  ro,umask=0222,defaults 0 0

To mount read-write:

/dev/sda1       /mymnt/win   ntfs-3g  rw,umask=0000,defaults 0 0

You can now mount it by running:

mount /mymnt/win

useful link pls try thins out
http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/ntfs-mount-on-red-hat-el-5-fatal-module-fuse-not-found-634201/
http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/rhel-centos-mounting-remote-filesystem-using-sshfs.html
http://www.centos.org/modules/newbb/viewtopic.php?topic_id=12307
http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-desktop-74/how-to-centos-5-ntfs-621688/